# TypoScript: select a specific content element from a column

Tags: typo3, typoscript

What is the best way to select a single content element?
I have a static html template like this:

```
<html>
...
<div class="left clearfix">
    <h1><img src="fileadmin/templates/images/ueberschrift_startseite.png" alt="Willkommen" /><span>Willkommen</span></h1>
    <p>EINLEITUNGSTEXT 1 EINLEITUNGSTEXT 1</p>
    <ul>
        <li>LI 1</li>
        <li>LI 2</li>
        <li>LI 3</li>
        <li>LI 4</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>HEADLINETEXT 3</h3>
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </p>
</div>
...
</html>
```

In my Backend I have added

1. A Content Element for the `<h1>`
2. A Content Element that should be displayed between the `<p>` Tags where now `Einleitungstext1` is displayed
3. A Content Element that contains the `LI` for the `UL` Section

and so on.

All Elements are in the same column.

I what to take my static HTML Template and fill several SPECIFIC parts with elements that can be edited in the backend.

I hope I could explain what my problem is.

How do you configure your templates? Is there a much better way to replace only specific parts of a static template?

Regards,
Max

Comment: How are you mapping your common layouts ? with TemplaVoila or standard templating system ?

Comment: i dont use templavoila! i want to go the classic way.

Comment: Should i create a backend layout with columns AND ROWS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know how to use `marks` and `subparts` in TypoScript, in such case what you have to do is set marks in your template, put each CE in separate column (maybe you'll need to add custom columns if all `left`, `default`, `right` and `border` (0-3) columns are used for other things) and finally just map these columns to the marks.

tip: TemplaVoila allows for more combinations as you can map not only container for CE's but also other things (header fields, image fields, TS snippets etc.)

Comment: yes.. in know how to use marks and subparts. I`m trying it now with several rows

Comment: Please read ``Modern Template Building`` and have a look at how the ``Introduction Package`` handles this.